# Laravel 5.3 - caching information schema queries

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use multiple domains for the same site structure, so almost all tables have the `domain_id` column. So, to NOT define the domain_id condition every time I am using the following approach (not sure if this is the best one)

I created `BaseModel` that other models are extending from and have this in `boot` method of that BaseModel

```
parent::boot();
static::addGlobalScope(new DomainScope());
```

and here is the apply method's content according to docs

```
if (Schema::hasColumn($model->getTable(), 'domain_id')) {
    $builder->where('domain_id', '=', DOMAIN_ID);
}
```

This works great, however if I have e.g. **5 find queries** on the **same page, to the same table** (just as an example) in debug panel I see **5 queries** like this

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'my_db_name' and table_name = 'my_table_name'
```

Now, I perfectly understand that to check whether the column exists in the table it gets the information from information schema, but why it is making the same query for the same table over and over again. I would presume It should make one request and then cache it, and for subsequent requests just read from cache.

**q1)** Does laravel internally cache this query ? I am thinking maybe because debug is enabled, that is why each time its making a query ? but cant find any verification of this

**q2)** and if it does not cache, can I cache it manually. I checked the laravel docs for adding a cache, but the problem here that query is not done by me, so I cant figure out to simply use `Cache::remember`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would suggest not to fire a query for checking if domain_id exists in the table every time. You can do this by simply adding a variable to your model that defines whether the model is a multi-domain model (has a domain_id column) or single domain model (no domain_id column) like so:

```
// In BaseModel.php
public $multiDomain = true; // override to false in your child model class if it's a single domain model
// In DomainScope apply method
if ($model->multiDomain)) {
    $builder->where('domain_id', '=', DOMAIN_ID);
}
```

If you don't want to use the above, you can cache like so:

```
if(Cache::remember($model->getTable() . "_domain", $minutes, function() use($model) {
    return Schema::hasColumn($model->getTable(), 'domain_id');
}) {
    $builder->where('domain_id', '=', DOMAIN_ID);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, the caching way worked. I wonder why this is not a built in feature

Comment: I think what's going on is that knowing the database schema could be considered somewhat of an antipattern, like how some developers think of introspection. I don't share this view, so I wish that someone would write a schema caching composer package that "just worked" for all edge cases including deployments and migrations. The issue has also been reported, but it's unlikely to ever get fixed: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17781 edit: I found one but haven't tested it: https://packagist.org/packages/yokuru/laravel-schema-cache